# Why visual studio code does not recognize my phone?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am new with flutter. when connecting the device the pc detects it but not the vscode
[image]

However, here I leave what flutter doctor throws. I'm new to flutter so I don't quite understand what they suggest. I already have usb debugging enabled developer options install via usb etc. it's a redmi 9a.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way:

1. Download [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)
2. Click Tools > SDK Manager. Or

[image]

In the SDK Tools tab,

[image]

In the SDK platforms tab, install any one android version

[image]

Go to the windows terminal and accept android licenses.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Make sure you have vs code extensions for flutter installed and then restart your VS Code.

You also have to enable USB debugging in developer options in your mobile in order to get detected by your PC

> There is a hard way too without installing android studio.